# Auto restart windows mobile when battery life gets approximately 10%

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

Windows Mobile 6.0 will switch the phone off on the device when the battery life gets to approximately 10%. So the user does not have to switch the phone back on once the battery life rises above 10%, it should be automatically. Can any body help on this:-

Can we achieve this using .net, if yes please provide sample code or reference.
How to achieve this functionality.

Thanks,
Mobility

Comment: You are touching the core functions of the Windows Mobile OS. I think this behavior will be affected by different phone hardware. May I ask which version of Windows Mobile you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919436.aspx) or [RIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918613.aspx) to change the power of the GSM or CDMA cellular radio.  Both API are pretty complex as far as Win32 API goes.  These API will work from Pocket PC 2002 through Windows Mobile 6.5.3.  It's possible to use these API from .NET but you will probably have to use Platform Invoke.

There is also the [SNAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.aspx), which has a managed wrapper.  This API requires Windows Mobile 5 or later.  See the SystemProperty.PhoneRadioOff enumeration for more information.